# React production files taking much more space on local server than on React's server

Tags: reactjs

I created a react app using create-react-app. The production version of the app on react's server is taking much less space(121 KB for the main JS file and 8.7 KB for the main CSS file) but then I copied the build folder and tried running it on apache server but it takes 413 KB for the JS file and 69 KB for the main CSS file.

I am not sure why this is happening. Could someone help out please?How can I reduce the size before eventually deploying it?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Are you sure that you refreshed your Browser the right way (try CTRL + F5) and that you have deleted the cache? Is there anything between your apache server and you (cloudflare, etc.)?

Comment: @Larce I found the reason. Apache server is not compressing the react files using gzip. I have been looking for solutions and they mention modifying .htaccess file but I couldn't find any.